# Issues with your app privacy details on the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone

We received below policy notification from AppStore in resolution center:

```
Hello, 

When you submitted your app, you answered questions about your app's privacy practices in App Store Connect. There are possible issues with the information you gave. You indicated that your app does not collect or track device or user data. However, your app integrates code from or communicates with third-parties that appear to collect and track this data, including, but not limited to, AppLovin. 

You need to provide accurate information about your app’s privacy practices, including the practices of all the third-party partners your app interfaces with, like ad networks, analytics tools, and SDKs. Doing so will help you avoid rejections on future submissions. If you don't know what data your third-party partners collect or if they track your users, please contact them or refer to the documentation they've made available. 

We have not rejected your submission, but this message will remain in Resolution Center for your reference. You do not need to reply after making the appropriate changes. We appreciate your efforts to comply with our guidelines and look forward to reviewing your future submissions to the App Store.

Learn more about app privacy details on the App Store and how to update privacy information in App Store Connect.

Best regards,

App Store Review
```

[image]

How to fix this issue ? Am I need to code anything related to SKAdNetworkIdentifier & App Tracking Transparancy Alert?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because App Store policy is off topic.

Comment: This is a bug in the App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to provide privacy policy url.

Example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JpNOfUb6mzwG-q5gQQn_oRveKlxvTrQKXjACtc2j47Y/edit?usp=sharing

Go to App Privacy Section in AppStore and update settings.

You need to mention what are the data Used to Track You and Data Linked to you.

[image]

Also update  SKAdNetworkIdentifier & App Tracking Transparancy Alert:

```
- (void)requestIDFA
{
    if (@available(iOS 14.0, *))
    {
        [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
            
            [self loadAllAds];
 
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self loadAllAds];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using the AppLovin MAX - I would advise using their built-in consent flow instead. Here are the docs: https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/ios/getting-started/consent-flow.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AppLovin Privacy Policy](https://www.applovin.com/privacy/), there is much more data than just the Device ID that's being collected by AppLovin SDK.

So you need to update your App Privacy (in App Store Connect) with accurate information.

And please, delete your previous **answer** with several images and move them to the original question (update the **question**).

Comment: with accurate information means what information actually? Please mention all

Comment: Sorry I can't mention all of them.You need to identify all of the data you or your third-party partners collect, unless the data meets all of the criteria for optional disclosure.

Comment: Instructions from Apple that could help you identify what usage must be listed: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/. And you definitely have to check the App Lovin Privacy Policy I've posted earlier in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for info provided.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a screw-up by Apple.  They say you are using "AppLovin".  Are you?  If not you are in the same bag as me.  I got the same notice claiming I use "Branch SDK" - but my app uses no third party software other than OpenSSL (to decode the IAP receipt).